# Ship flutter app with pre populated SQLite DB data

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I'm new to Flutter and I wanted to know what is the best practice to ship the flutter app with pre-populated SQLite DB data ( default data ).

Also in future app updates, I may update the default data. Means, if someone installs the app for the first time, the new default data should install. And if someone updates the app, it should update the existing data in his SQLite DB accordingly.

What should be the right way?

Answer (score 2):

I would look at moor, it has a MigrationStrategy, there is a callback onCreate and beforeOpen that has some goodies like wasCreated which you could use to precreate tables and prepopulate data on first run. Take a look at the docs and the source code for more details.
https://moor.simonbinder.eu/docs/advanced-features/migrations/

Answer (score 0):

1. You can put loading data to onCreate callback, after all tables are initialized.
2. If you have to update data from time to time from the files, but don't want to increase db version, you can put it to onOpen callback and do check before returning database, like if number rows in tableA <= 10 do table update.
3. You can use onUpgrade callback to run table updates, but in this case you have to increate db version every time you do data update.